# Visual Studio - auto generate entities and web front end?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, orm, c#-4.0

I went to the Visual Studio 2010 launch and remember seeing someone generate entites (which I am using and is awesome) from a database, but then taking it a step further and creating a web front end.  The front end would allow modification/deletion of existing data and addition of new, and it was all generated.

It was ugly, of course, but I would like to play around with it.  I can't remember what it was called though.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Generation of a nice web front end for a database can be via LightSwitch, http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch. It is a new product being pushed. Currently it is only in beta, but it can do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was probably ASP.NET Dynamic Data: http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if you can add a page or two to existing projects?

Comment: As far as I know, you can actually edit the generated pages. So it should be possible to add either dynamic data pages to another project or add other pages to a dynamic data project.